# TypeError: Could not convert group Bgroup. Output is truncated

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

code :
gender_group = df.groupby(['gender']).mean()
gender_group

[image: dataset]

error :
[image: error]

I searched on python document.

(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to *turn on* `numeric_only` in [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html)  :

```
gender_group = df.groupby("gender").mean(numeric_only=True)
```

​
Output :

```
print(gender_group)

        math_score  reading_score  writing_score  total score  average
gender                                                                
female       77.00          85.67          85.00       247.67    82.56
male         61.50          67.50          59.50       188.50    62.83
```